# How to open a page in new tab in flutter web?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I want to open a page in a new tab, but could not find any code. Any help or idea, please?
I am not asking about opening a URL on a new page...
I just want to open the page in a new tab on button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import 'package:universal_html/html.dart' as html;

 static openNewTab({String setUrl, String setTitle}) {
    return html.window.open(
      setUrl,
      setTitle,
    );
  }
```

Comment: How can we give the URL of any app's screen?

Comment: Sorry i cannot understand,will you explain in brief!